# Numpy random choice preserving original ordering

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say we have an array `a = [5, 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 9]`

I want to choose a few elements (without replacement) so that the relative order of the chosen elements will be the same as in an input array.
Using the `random.choice` with `shuffle=False` doesn't seem to do this.

```
a = [5, 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 9]
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
rng.choice(a, 4, replace=False, shuffle=False)
```

Output:

```
array([9, 5, 1, 8])
```

I want to see:

```
array([5, 8, 1, 9])
```

What's the simplest way to achieve this result?

Comment: Can the original list have duplicates?

Comment: If not, use `random.choices()` to get the choices, then use `sort()` to get it back into the original order.

Comment: Pick a random element from the entire original list. For the next random element, pick a random element from a sliced version of the original list which starts at the index of the previous random element +1. Repeat.

Comment: @PaulM.: That produces a heavily skewed probability distribution if you don't pick weights carefully.

Comment: @PaulM. That might not work -- if you pick the last element of the list, there won't be any more to select.

Answer (score 3):

One method I can think of is to randomly choose indices first, and then filter the original list according to this set of indices:

```py
import random

a = [5, 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 9]

idx = set(random.sample(range(len(a)), k=4))
output = [x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i in idx]

print(output) # [5, 2, 3, 1]
```

Using numpy under the same idea,

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

a = np.array([5, 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 9])

output = a[sorted(default_rng().choice(range(len(a)), size=4, replace=False))]
print(output) # [5 3 4 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample `k` random elements and sort the result according to the index in `lst`:

```
import random

def select_k_sorted(lst, k):
    return sorted(random.sample(lst, k), key=lst.index)
```